# function that replaces consecutive duplicate elements of list with single element

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops

What I tried :

```
def compress(l):
    i = 0
    while i < len(l)-1:
        if l[i] == l[i+1]:
            del l[i]
        else:
            i = i+1
l = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5]
compress(l)
```

I do not know many functions in python yet as I have just started so I would like to do this the basic way i.e using for and while loops and some list methods.
What am I doing wrong? 
Any other methods
Another one I tried what's wrong in this  :

```
def compress(l):
    for i in l:
        if l[i] == l[i+1] and i != (len(l) - 1):
            l.pop(l[i])

        print(l)
l = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,5,6,7,8]
compress(l)
```

which gives me the output :

```
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't appear to be doing *anything* wrong<sup>(a)</sup> with your first attempt, other than the fact you're not printing the compressed list. That can be fixed by adding this as the last line:

```
print(l)
```

At that point, you should see:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

like I do.

---

Your *second* attempt is problematic - it's a common occurrence when you modify a list that you're iterating over. Because the iteration effectively examines based on the index, inserting items before the current point can result in items being processed twice. Additionally, deleting items at or before the current point can result in items not being processed at all.

That latter case is what's happening in your second attempt.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> You could probably choose more descriptive names for your variables than `l` but that's just a preference of mine.

Comment: Actually as I have just started I usually give variable names in short form.I will be descriptive from now on

Comment: I don't seen any particular reason why a function parameter needs a more descriptive name here. It's not like there are other values it needs to be distinguished from. `l` is a bad variable name for other reasons, though. (`l`, `1`, `I` all look similar, depending on your font.)

Comment: @chepner: `def compress(l):` gives *no* indication as to what should be passed so, unless you know already, you have to examine the code. Something like `listToRemoveConsecutiveDupesFrom`, despite the absurd verbosity, is still a better name. Perhaps a shorter name would be okay if there were comments (still not `l`, for the reasons you point out) but I tend to prefer the code to tell me what's needed, simply because code and comments sometimes diverge over time.

Comment: That's what a doc string (or other documentation) is for.

Comment: @chepner: hence my comment "simply because code and comments sometimes diverge over time" :-) Assuming they're kept in sync, I have no issue with that.

Comment: Also, the *function name* is the important part. Since there's only one parameter, there's nothing particularly interesting you can say about it that the function doesn't already tell you.

Comment: Then `compress` is equally deficient. Is `l` a list? Is it a file on disk? If a list, is it a series of string to concatenate and run Huffman over, or is it a list of files to compress, one at a time? That's why I prefer the code-as-comments. But, to be honest, this is probably worthy as a *separate* question rather than clogging up comments here, though it would probably be closed as opinion-generating :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo I have understood what you said but if have to make changes in my second what do you suggest.I have been burning my brain over this

Comment: @Tanmay: my advice would be not to use the second, the first is perfectly adequate (for more performance, you could use the answer by schwobaseggl but it's probably not necessary unless your lists get really big or you need to process them *many* times per second). If you still want to iterate over a list and make changes, that's the approach you should take: create a *new* list so you're not modifying the old while iterating, then just replace the old list elements with the new.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are asking for other methods, one should point out that repeated removal from a list has bad performance, as all the tail elements have to be shifted for each removal. Building the compressed list from scratch is less expensive and slice assignment allows you to mutate the original list. Using basic loops and list methods, I would do:

```
def compress(l):
    new_l = l[:1]
    for x in l:
        if x != new_l[-1]:
             new_l.append(x)
    l[:] = new_l
```

For a one-line alternative using some more advanced means ([`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)), you can do:

```
from itertools import groupby

def compress(l):
    l[:] = [k for k, _ in groupby(l)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to try so hard to delete duplicate elements in a list:

```
print(list(set(l)))
```

this will delete all the duplicate elements in the list.

Comment: That's a good succinct answer but it *may* not be what's needed (though check with OP). The question called for consecutive duplicates to be removed but this will both remove non-consecutive dupes and end up with a possibly different order. In other words, `[1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1]` may become `[2, 1]`.

Comment: sorted(set(x), key=x.index) This wil solve the issue if order is a bother.

Comment: groupby from itertools would be an option. @Python hub, the list of paxdiabli shoud result in [1,2,1] - yours gives [1,2] or [2,1] - the seconds consecutive 1's are also eleminated by using set.

Comment: Yeah, in that case, we have to use groupby from itertools but just for eliminating duplicate elements, we can use set(). Thanks for providing me a piece of knowledge.